# How to display a reminder window on any page of application

Tags: php, codeigniter, reminders

In my web application, users will be able to set reminders for upcoming tasks and events. I am developing the application using CodeIgniter (PHP) with model-view-controller base.
I set the database table needed for reminders. I will run my reminder controller with job server. And my confusion starts here. This controller will call the view file which is a popup window. But I need to be displaying this reminder popup window on the page which user is on. How can I display a view on another? Or what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to a Modal Window. If that is the case, you'll need to work with JS/jQuery or/and CSS. You can Google it and find lots of tutorials about Modals. If not so please expend your question.

Answer (score -2):

you should make another PHP file and include that file in each file where you want the reminder window.

1. in the common file there should be some function like "setInterval"
   then call modal via js or jquery.

2.maybe it helps(both are in the same file)

**JS**

```
setInterval(tick, 30000); function tick() { 
   //get the mins of the current time 
   var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
   if(mins == "18"|| mins == "19" || mins == "20"||mins == "21" || mins == "22" || mins == "23"){
      $('#reminder').modal('show'); 
     beep(); 
   } 
}
```

**HTML (Bootstrap modal)**

```
<div id="reminder" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" > 
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style=" margin-top: 150px; ">
            <div class="modal-content"> 
               <div class="modal-header"> 
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
                   </button> 
                   <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:red;">
                       Reminder
                   </h4>
               </div> 
               <div class="modal-body" id="reminder_body"> 
               <script> 
                   load_reminder();
               </script>  
              </div> 
         <div class="modal-footer"> 
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" >
                    Ok
             </button> 
       </div>
```